# How can I add text to an email with screenshot pic

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that sends a screenshot picture of a range> I would like to add text to the email but have not been able to figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

'''

```
        Public Sub ScreenShotResults2()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim olApp As Object
        Dim Email As Object
        Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
        Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("B20:I34")
            rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With
    
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
        'strbody = "See production data for most recent 3 months.  "
    
        With Email
            .To = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B22").Value
            .Subject = "4 Month LO Production Lookback for " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B22").Value
            '.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "</p>" & strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
            .Display
        
            wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
            'if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
             With wdDoc
                .InlineShapes(1).Height = 250
             End With
    
            .Display
        End With
    
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    
        Set Email = Nothing
        Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `strbody` not work? By photo, do you mean the output of the `RangetoHTML(rng)` function? A little more info would be useful. Based on your code, what is currently happening vs what you expect to be happening?

Comment: I am not using the strbody or the rangetoHTML because I get errors. I cannot combine the screenshot method with the RangetoHTML function. I need it as a pic to keep the conditional formatting. So I am using the code that takes a screenshot of the range instead of the RangetoHTML function.

Comment: So I guess the question is how can I add text to the body of the email and a screenshot of a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to add the text. Here is one:

```
    'if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
    With wdDoc
        .InlineShapes(1).Height = 250
        .Paragraphs.Add
        .Paragraphs.Add
        .Content.InsertAfter "Please look at the range image!"
    End With
```

***EDIT:*** here is an expanded example to add text before and after the image (without using `RangeToHTML`)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ScreenShotResults2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("B20:I34")
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    With Email
        .To = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B22").Value
        .Subject = "4 Month LO Production Lookback for " & _
                   Worksheets("Summary").Range("B22").Value
        .Display
    End With
    
    With wdDoc.Content
        '--- paste the range image first, because it overwrites
        '    everything in the document
        .PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        
        '--- now add our greeting at the start of the email
        .InsertBefore "Dear Goober," & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "See production data for most recent 3 months.  " & _
                      vbCr & vbCr
                                   
        '--- finally add our sign off after the image
        .InsertAfter vbCr & vbCr & _
                     "This is my final comment." & vbCr & vbCr & _
                     "Sincerely," & vbCr & _
                     "Me!"
    End With
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow! this kinda worked, but is there a way to make it the first sentence, a carriage return and then the picture? I tried InsertBefore but it just tabs the picture to the right. I would like the text than a blank line and then the picture. Can you tweak please and thank you :-)

Comment: @MEC see additional code in the answer

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you taking the time to complete :-)

Comment: @urdearboy - I used to use the `RangeToHTML` function (and still may), but I've lately found that working directly with the `WordEditor` is (perhaps more) straightforward as well. I've learned a lot in that regard.